# Check users resolution in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

is it possible to behave according to the user's resolution?

Comment: Sure. http://www.google.com/search?q=Check+users+resolution+in+css

Comment: I don't understand why people are +1 ing the comment above. Not only is it smart arsed and unhelpful but also wrong! @Casey if there is a way to do this in css lets see your answer.

Comment: Yup, the comment is basically wrong. However, if you need to behave according to user's resolution, probably you have a problem in you code.

Comment: The actual question asks if it is possible to behave according to screen resolution. You can have different stylesheets and therefore different layouts depending on the user's screen resolution (see kennebec's answer), so I believe "yes" is a correct answer to this question.

Comment: @Casey I guess you're right on that one. For some reason I thought it was asking whether you could *get* the screen res in css. Still you should see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with CSS, no. But with JS, sure.

```
if (window.screen.width <= 800 && window.screen.height <= 600) {
    //do something();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

css3 media queries will allow you to apply stylesheets or @media rules 
according to the size of the client, among other properties.

They don't fallback in non comforming browsers, so they are not ripe for general use,
but if you are young it may be worth learning how it is done.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

To apply a style sheet to a document when displayed on a screen  greater than 800 pixels wide:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" >
```

To apply a style sheet to a document when displayed on any device less than 400 pixels wide:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 400px)" >
```

This media query expresses rules for screen and handheld devices if 
the width of the viewport is greater than 20em.

```
@media handheld and (min-width: 20em), screen and (min-width: 20em) { ... }
```

The ‘em’ value is relative to the font size of the root element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the resolution with CSS. But you can make up fluid designs.

Take a look at [Little boxes](http://www.thenoodleincident.com/tutorials/box_lesson/boxes.html) for some great starters.

Grz, Kris.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in standard CSS. Maybe it'll be OK in (only) IE browsers.

Or you can use JavaScript.