# How to get screen height in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently using $(window).height() to get a screens height . but this is returning 0 in firefox . any other way to get height in firefox ??

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937494/why-does-firefox-return-0-as-the-value-of-window-height

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079341/check-users-resolution-in-css)
might help you

2 options cited there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `screen.height` and `screen.width` properties ,to find out screen size.
[**For more info**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.height)